# How can I get path of 3rd party app in Django settings.py

Tags: python, django, django-celery-beat

I install `django_celery_beat` app in Django `settings.py` file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...,
'django_celery_beat',
```

]

It has its own `locale` dir.

[image]

As I understand I need to add **this path** to `LOCALE_PATHS` in `settings.py`. How can I get it? Hardcoding is not an option, of cause.

Comment: Actually there's no need for you to add the `locale` folder location to `LOCALE_PATHS` because Django is already checking for folders named `locale` inside your apps included in `INSTALLED_APPS`. In the docs (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations-1) you can see this in point 2.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @mtzd I see that `./manage.py compilemessages` doesn't find `*.po` files of 3rd party package `django_celery_beat`

Comment: @DeepakTripathi 3rd party package has `locale` dir with `*.po` files but they aren't used by Django

Comment: Without `LOCALE_PATHS` Django doesn't find translation files. I don't know if it is my specific case or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the following solutions that works:

```
import importlib

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    ...,
    os.path.join(        
        os.path.dirname(importlib.util.find_spec('django_celery_beat').origin),
        'locale/',
    ),
]
```